# Ubuntu 12.04 Nvidia driver for GeForce GTX 770 is activated but will not load and is not in use

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with a GeForce GTX 770 (product no. P4-2773-KR). A few days ago, after a reboot, the Nvidia driver stopped working. The "Additional Drivers" windows says that nvidia driver version 331-updates is "activated but not currently in use". The monitor resolution is limited to 1024x768. The excerpts from the Xorg log and the syslog mentioning nvidia are copied below:

Xorg.0.log

```
[     2.165] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[     2.165] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     2.166] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[     2.229] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     2.229]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     2.229]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     2.229] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.123  Wed Jul  2 11:19:55 PDT 2014
[     2.229] Loading extension GLX
[     2.229] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     2.229] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[     2.235] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     2.235]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     2.235]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     2.246] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module. Please check your
[     2.246] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages.
[     2.246] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[     2.246] (II) Unloading nvidia
[     2.246] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module-specific error, 0)
```

syslog

```
Nov 10 19:11:32 rll3 kernel: [    1.680235] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Nov 10 19:11:32 rll3 kernel: [    1.680238] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Nov 10 19:11:32 rll3 kernel: [    1.683502] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
Nov 10 19:11:32 rll3 kernel: [    1.683727] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
```